# MongoDB Integration Practice for Dockerized Python Project on GitHub

Tags: python, mongodb, git, docker, github

I'm in the process of integrating Docker with a Python project hosted on GitHub. This project involves a Jupyter Notebook application and utilizes a MongoDB database. As I'm collaborating with a small group of developers, I'm seeking guidance on the most effective approach to managing the MongoDB server within our development environment.

Given that the database is expected to be relatively small in size, I'd like to explore strategies for handling the MongoDB instance. Here are a few questions I have:

1. **MongoDB Instance Management**: What would be the best practice for managing the MongoDB instance for a small-scale project with a limited number of developers? I'm interested in an approach that balances simplicity and efficiency.
2. **Backup and Restore**: Should we consider implementing a backup and restore strategy for the MongoDB database? This would help safeguard against data loss and provide a way to restore the database in case of unexpected issues.
3. **Version Control for MongoDB Data**: Given the compact size of the database, is it advisable to include a backup of the MongoDB data in our GitHub repository? What are the potential benefits and drawbacks of including the database backup as part of the version-controlled codebase?

In essence, I'm looking for guidance on managing the MongoDB component of our project in a streamlined manner that aligns with best practices for small-scale development teams.

---

**Simplified Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY notebooks /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

**Simplified docker-compose.yml (with MongoDB integrated):**

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: test_jupyter_container
    image: test-jupyter-image:latest
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: test_mongo_container
    image: mongo:4.4.10
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data:/data/db

volumes:
  test_mongodb_data:
```

These configurations include the MongoDB service integrated into the `docker-compose.yml` file. The MongoDB service will work in tandem with the Jupyter service.